# When can we write $B=A^{\dagger}A?$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, mathematics

Consider ladder operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ of a quantum harmonic oscillator. Now again say we define an operator $B=B(a,a^{\dagger})$ which is hermitian i.e., $B=B^{\dagger}$. The question is when can we write it in terms of another operator $A$ as,

$$B=A^{\dagger}A?$$

What are the restrictions that one has to impose on $B$ to be above to write in this form?

Comment: The operator $A^\dagger A$ is positive semi-definite. But why exactly do you introduce the (harmonic oscillator ?) ladder operators here?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I need it for some other thing that I am doing. Can we always find this $A$ in terms of $a,a^{\dagger}$, if $B$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: I don't understand. What is $B$? In case $A$ itself is positive, it is the (unique) positive square root operator $A=\sqrt B$. Does that help?

Comment: @TobiasFünke $B$ is some hermitian operator written which depends on $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$.

Comment: Ok. Then it is just as @Valter Moretti writes: $B=A^\dagger A$ if and only if $B$ is positive (semi-definite). And one particular choice then is $A=\sqrt B$, which then gives you $A$ as a function of $a,a^\dagger$.

Comment: 1. Please do indicate that you posted this also [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844451/when-can-we-write-a-daggera-b) --and also indicate there that you've crossposted it here. 2. Consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer or take appropriate action (e.g. clarify either via comments or edit the question what exactly is still unclear, not answered etc.) This also holds for all of your other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $B:D(B)\to H$ is selfadjoint, where $D(B)$ is the dense linear domain of $B$ in the Hilbert space $H$, necessary and sufficient condition for writing the operator as $B=A^\dagger A$ for some other operator $A$, is that $B$ is positive: $\langle \psi|B\psi\rangle\geq 0$ if $\psi \in D(B)$.

I stress that when I write
$$B=A^\dagger A$$
I also mean that the domain of $B$ coincides with the one of $A^\dagger A$. The latter is
$$D(A^\dagger A) = \{ x \in D(A)\:|\: Ax \in D(A^\dagger)\}$$
per definition. Without this specification it is very difficult to give a definite answer.

$A$ is not unique, but all possible $A$ have the form $U\sqrt{A}$ where $U:H\to H$ is a partial isometry such that $U^\dagger U = I$ on the range of $A$ (which coincides with the range of its square root).

Comment: Are there more general characteristics when $B$ is not self-adjoint (or closed)? I was just thinking about that when writing my comment. In finite dimensions (or for bounded operators) everything is clear (but OP seems to be explicitly working in infinite-dimensions).

Comment: I removed closed, because if the decomposition is possible for a closed operator it is necessarily also selfadjoint. Concerning your issue, well if the decomposition holds and $A$ is closed densely defined, then $B$ is necessarily selfadjoint. So there are no many chances if $B$ is not selfadjoint.